# Array prints just zeros

Tags: c, arrays, random, printf, format-specifiers

I have created an array with random numbers, but when I print the array they are all 0, what is wrong here? I know that the random numbers are there, but still zeros?

```
int superArray[SIZE];
int index, counter;

srand( time(0) );

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)  //random numbers

    superArray[index] = rand() % 21  +1;

for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)  //vertical print
{
    printf("%8.f\n", superArray[index]);
}
printf("%8d\n\n", superArray[8]); //verify that array has random numbers
```

Comment: And `printf("%8d\n\n", superArray[8]);` does not horizontally print the array. Use `for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++){ printf("%d ", superArray[index]); }` instead

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour; read the manual for `printf`.

Comment: if you were to have compiled with the warnings enabled (for gcc, at least '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'  then your compiler would have flagged: 1) the first printf() statement as the format modifier does not match the parameter type.     2) The parameter to time() is a pointer type, so 0 is not correct, use NULL.  BTW: when asking a run time question, please post code that compiles.  The posted code doesn't.  It is missing the #include statements, and a function to contain the code.

Answer (score 5):

Print `int` with `%d` and it will work:

```
printf("%d\n", superArray[index]);
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR;** -using wrong format specifier is undefined behavior.

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter `7.21.6.1`, `fprintf()`

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

`superArray` is an array of `int`s. You should be using the `%d` format specifier to print the value.

That said,

```
 printf("%8d\n\n", superArray[8]);
```

does not print *all* 8 elements, one after another, as you *might* have thought.

Even if you did not think like above, `superarray[8]` *maybe* invalid, if the `SIZE` value is less than `9`, because in `C` array indexing starts from 0.

Comment: yes this was the error, my array is SIZE = 20   :o) I printed array number 8 to see if the array was really empty as the other print command suggested, it was just a test

Comment: @AndersBruun as I told, `SIZE` more than 9 will be fine, but it won't print all the elements, it will only print the 9th element in that case. :)